# How do we show custom holidays in calendar?

Tags: usability, web-app, calendar

I wanted to show custom holidays in the calendar component. I am already displaying Saturday and Sunday in gray color. Now I wanted to show two other categories of holidays which are real banking and user defined holidays.

My Calendar Component looks like this [image: Calendar Image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZdZq.png">

The real banking holidays are pre-defined holidays by the application and the user defined holidays are those user can define as their own.

I am looking for different representations for the both the holidays.

Already used colors in the calendar :

1. Gray : for Saturday and Sunday
2. Sky blue : Today
3. Red or Dark Blue : Text on each cell.

Please share your ideas.

Comment: Usually, all non-work days should be shown in a common way that clearly distinguishes them from work days. If you use background color to differentiate them you cannot use it for anything else except _maybe_ Today. This extends to Week an Month views. That ‘maybe’ is true when using color in a multidimensional way, e.g. hue and saturation, so blue Today works with light and dark grays only if the blue can also be light and dark.

Comment: You can just allow the user to define the background color of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Who is looking at this calendar? I assume the employee, his supervisors and perhaps HR. Although chances are you'll be providing a different view for the supervisor/HR use case.  It would make sense if the color code continues through all use cases.

I put yellow as vacation in the one I created and there was space to write "Labor Day", etc... for Federal Holidays. Employees could easily tell if the holiday was a company wide holiday. It looks as if there is space in your case as well.

I experimented with different colors for personal v corporate and employees didn't care about that. There was an accompanying chart that told employees the days off they had accrued, days left and broke it down by Federal Holiday, personal day, vacation and sick day.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mayo, This calendar is a part of anaccounting software. Calendar tells the user when to make the payments. So in case of a holiday we need to give him a heads up.Here the categorization of holidays does matter because the user may not be able to make the payment on an banking holiday.